# adding HTTP_REFERER in header and verify

Tags: php, http-referer

Now a days most of the users turn off HTTP_REFERRER or their browser do it so.
Most of the browser now dont send HTTP_REFERRER can i add this in header while serving pages to the browser so next time i can get the HTTP_REFERRER ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The referrer is set by the browser. It's nothing that you control from your end. With that said, most people don't disable it and most browser do sent it.

According to [RFC2616 Section 14.36](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The Referer field MUST NOT be sent if
>   the Request-URI was obtained from a
>   source that does not have its own URI,
>   such as input from the user keyboard.